# Detailed reference with page and section name

Tags: cross-referencing

So, I have next screenshoot of document:
[image]

How to replicate that "*See Section 1.2.2.1 [POSIX Safety Concepts], page 2*"?

("*POSIX Safety Concepts*" is a section name, all the text mentioned above within `"` is clickable link to corresponding page)

Comment: Do you mean to cite a reference with more content, such as, `This is a reference [24, p.8]`.

Comment: Have a look at varioref (https://ctan.org/pkg/varioref), which is part of topic https://ctan.org/topic/label-ref

Comment: @Clara Something like that. I mean, I will place `\label{xxx}` and refer to it with some other command than `\ref{xxx}`, so it will print additional info such as `See <section/equalation/theorem/chapter> 1.2.3.4 [<section/equalation/theorem/chapter name>] on page <page>`

Comment: Maybe you are searching [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) or [`nameref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref)? You could also help us adding a minimal working example to your question and use that to explain your problem. This is often more helpful than only a screenshot.

Comment: @cabohah https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf 5.10 Finding Tokens in a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been using `cleverref` before. I read its documentation and got everything I need exluding `\nameref` command. So I explored `nameref` package and got what I wanted.
Thanks @cabohah for pointing out about `nameref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paper=a4paper,
inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, 
bindingoffset=0cm, 
textwidth=\textwidth, textheight=\textheight, 
includehead=false, includefoot=false, portrait, twoside}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
notefont=\normalfont\sffamily, notebraces={}{},
headfont=\bfseries\itshape,
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
headformat=\NAME\ \NUMBER \NOTE,
headpunct=\sffamily.\\,
spaceabove=5mm, spacebelow=5mm,
postheadspace=0mm, headindent=3mm,
]{thmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section, name=Теорема]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle, numberwithin=section, name=Означення]{dfn}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefname{section}{Розд.}{Розд.}
\crefname{page}{стр.}{стр.}
\crefname{thm}{трм.}{трм.}
\Crefname{thm}{Трм.}{Трм.}
\crefname{dfn}{озн.}{озн.}
\Crefname{dfn}{Озн.}{Озн.}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{(Див. \hyperref[#1]{\nameCref{#1}\ \labelcref*{#1}\ [\nameref*{#1}], \cpageref{#1}})}

\begin{document}
    \section{Вступ}
    Бла бла бла
    
    \section{Теореми та визначення}
    \label{sec:b}
\begin{thm}[Диз'юктивне розкладання булевої функція за \(k\) змінними]
    \label{thm:dnf:k}
    Будь-яку булеву функцію \(f(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)\) можна зобразити в такій формі:
    \begin{multline}
        f(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)
        =\bigvee_{\mathclap{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n)}}
        x_1^{\sigma_1}\land x_2^{\sigma_2}\land\dots\land x_k^{\sigma_k}\land 
        f(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_k, x_{k-1},\dots,x_n)
    \end{multline}
\end{thm}
\begin{dfn}[Двійковий параметер \(\sigma\) і позначення \(x^\sigma\)]
    \label{dfn:bin}
    \begin{gather}
        x, \sigma \in \mathbb{B},\\
        x^\sigma = \begin{cases}\overline{x},\ \text{якщо }\sigma = 0,\\ x,\ \text{якщо } \sigma = 1.\end{cases}
    \end{gather}
\end{dfn}

\section{Роздуми}
\dots за теоремою 5. \fullref{thm:dnf:k}\\
\dots з списку теорем та визначень. \fullref{sec:b}\\
\dots визначення. \fullref{dfn:bin}
    
\section{Кінець}
\end{document}
```

[image]